# how to resolve definition(GoDef) with gopls when I don't have go.mod file

Tags: go, bazel, neovim, gopls, bazel-gazelle

I have a project, which doesn't use go.mod, and not follow the structure that project is under `$GOPATH/src/...`. It uses bazel and WORKSPACE file to manage depedencies.

I use gopls in neovim, and it could not resolve imports like `import github.com/pkg/errors`, so I am thinking to install the package one by one. However, `go get` needs to be with a `go.mod` file, and `go install` only works when installing a binary.

What option I have here? Thanks!